# error 'MODULE NOT FOUND', Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I am trying to resole the pathing issues:

this is what my files structure look like:
/www/html/

- /database/

1. databaseConnection.js

- /scripts/

1. LoginPageScript.js

- server.js
- index.html

in the database js file, the following code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE
});


pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connetcting to database: ', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connection to database succefully established!');
});

module.exports = { pool };
```

exports pool module, I assume

now i am trying to import pool into another script, in this case LoginPageScript.js, using:

`const { pool } = require('../database/databaseConnection.js');`

but the error thrown is:

```
Cannot find module '../database/databaseConnection'
Require stack:
- /var/www/html/scripts/LoginPageScript.js
- /var/www/html/server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/scripts/LoginPageScript.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/var/www/html/scripts/LoginPageScript.js',
    '/var/www/html/server.js'
  ]
}
```

I tried experimenting with different pathing like:

1. /database/databaseConnection.js
2. ./database/databaseConnection.js
3. ../database/databaseConnection.js

none seem to be working

Comment: Can you try to add the `.js` extension to the module import for safety? Not sure what node falls back to by default these days, but it might be that.

Comment: Still the error persists

Comment: What file is the initial file you are running from? `node server.js`? If so, your paths should be relative to that path (unless you use _cwd_ etc, but thats complicated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try traversing via dot annotation to `databaseConnection.js` file.**

And try using:

```
const { pool } = require('./database/databaseConnection.js');
```

Comment: still the error persists: Error: Cannot find module 'path/database/databaseConnection.js'

Comment: What exactly the path using dot annotation ?

Comment: you mean:
const { pool } = require('path/database/databaseConnection.js');

Comment: Dont use path.. Just use dotannotation and traverse the path

Comment: from the level of directory you are in  const { pool } = require('./database/databaseConnection.js');

Comment: I need to go up one directory and then to the /scripts folder, so I assume it would look like this: 
const { pool } = require('../database/databaseConnection.js');

Comment: still nothing.
also, the database folder is not within the scripts folder, it is in the root directory, as shown at the top of the question

Comment: `const { pool } = require('./database/databaseConnection.js');` try this

Comment: already tried, still nothing. I seems like my js files cannot leave their own directory, go to the parent's and enter different ones.

Comment: are you using any es6 moduling?

Comment: yes, for example express

Comment: Your path should be relative to the file that started it all - so it matters how this server gets started. Is it ran as `node server.js` or something? If so, then your path should start from there. Also, @NaviteLogger , you are not using ES Modules (as that would use `import` and `export` statements of `.mjs` files). You are using the old CommonJS system (`module.exports = ...` and `require`)

Comment: @NaviteLogger did last suggestion worked?